# Enum and functions

Tags: c#, function, enums

How to create a function which gets an enum and print it values and names at the same time?
If this is my Enum:

---

```
    public enum DaysOfWeek
    {
        monday,
        tuesday,
        wednesday
    }
```

---

I tried :

### but it's not working

```
    public void ShowEnum(Enum EnumList)
    {
        foreach (var route in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumList)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{(int)route} - {route}");
        }
    }
```

---

I wish to print :

0 - monday
1 - tuesday
2 - wednesday

---

Comment: Use `Enum.GetValues` to get all values of an enum. Cast an enum member to `int` to get its numeric value, or call `ToString` to get its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these ( all code was tested in Visual Studio and works properly):

```
var i=1;
foreach (DaysOfWeek dayOfWeek in (DaysOfWeek[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine( i.ToString() +" - " dayOfWeek.ToString());
       i+=1;
    }
```

or maybe (it will start from 0)

```
foreach (DaysOfWeek dayOfWeek in (DaysOfWeek[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine( ((int) dayOfWeek).ToString() + " - "+  dayOfWeek.ToString());
    }
```

Or

```
public static void EnumPrint<T>() where T : Enum
{
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var t in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine((i).ToString() + " - " + t.ToString());
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

or in one line:

```
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek));
```

Comment: DaysOfWeek  is just an example for an enum.
It should be a function

Comment: Enum can't be as T.
Enum is a special class

Comment: Did you read that all code was tested and working properly?

Comment: The [Enum constraint was added in C# 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints)

Comment: Well, I just update my VS and it's working! 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already got pretty close - I figured [Enum.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.format?view=netframework-4.8) is the way to go:

```
public static void ShowEnum<T>() where T : Enum
{
    foreach (var t in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Enum.Format(typeof(T), t, "d")} - {t}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the name of enumeration value in this way

```
Enum.GetName<DaysOfWeek>(value)
```

Therefore

```
        public void ShowEnum(Enum EnumList)
        {
            foreach (var route in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumList)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{(int)route} - {Enum. GetName<DayOfWeek>(route) }");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (I cant try it in VS right now)

```
public void ShowEnum<TEnum>()
    where TEnum : Enum
{
    foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{(int)enumValue} - {enumValue}");
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a generic parameter `TEnum` in the method with an `Enum` constraint, so you can pass any enum to the method.

usage:

```
ShowEnum<DaysOfWeek>();
```

If you don't have Enum generic constraint, you are using older C# version (this constraint was introduced in C# 7.3)

If this is the situation, you need some extra check, like this:

```
public void ShowEnum<TEnum>()
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("TEnum is not an enum");
    }

    foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{(int)enumValue} - {enumValue}");
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can't do that.
the error it shows me:
Provides the base class for enumerations.
Constraint cannot be special class 'Enum'

Comment: Updated the answer. If you cant use the Enum generic constraint, you use an older version of C#.

Comment: This works with newer versions of C#, though you should really constrain `TEnum` to be both `Enum` and `struct`. If you can't use a recent version of C#, constrain `TEnum` to be a `struct` and throw if the cast to `Enum` fails